# How to draw a polygon in google fusion tables

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to draw a polygon with Google fusion tables so that in the end, i can have a column called geometry which i'll use to query. All I have now is both the latitude and longitude of the point. How can I do that? Any assistant will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to do?  The "geometry" column needs to be "sort of" KML (a KML "geometry").  How do you expect to transform a "point" (a single latitude and longitude coordinate) into a Polygon (a set of latitude and longitude coordinates that define a shape)?

Comment: I have two columns, latitude and longitude both with points of various places. I want to combine both the latitude and Longitude to one column called geometry. How do I go about doing that? My table is in form of a .csv file

Comment: I would use a text editor.